# проблема в вызове метода в laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, классы, laravel5, model

Есть класс (модель) в которой есть константы, и мне необходимо их получать. Я создал метод в модели:

```
public static function method()
{
    return [
        self::constant,
    ];
}
```

С помощью которого вытаскиваю все константы в массиве. После чего создал route::get и там вызываю метод в классе, который в свою очередь вызывает этот метод. В итоге у меня должен возвращаться массив с константами, а возвращается ошибка: `No query results for model [App\Class]`. Если тестировать через `php artisan tinker`, и вызвать этот метод у класса (как модели так и контроллера), то всё правильно вернётся массив с константами, но при вызове на сайте, в реальных условиях - ошибка. Может кто-то знает как исправить?

Код метода в модели:

```
public static function getConsts(): array
{   
    return [
        self::CONST
    ];
}
```

Код метода в контроллере:

```
public function getConsts(): ApiResponse
{
    $consts = Class::getConsts();

    return new ApiSuccess('success', ['consts ' => $consts]);
}
```

Вызов в routes/api.php

```
Route::get('consts', 'ClassController@getConsts');
```

Comment: Попробовал сделать возврат массива прямо из метода контроллера, путём получения констант способом - Class::constant. Но не помогло, то же самое.

Comment: Добавьте остальной код, и конкретно те функции где вы вызываете данный метод, и он выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: Добавил, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: попробуйте $this->metodOrConst;

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, поставьте как ответ, я приму.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте

```
$this->metodOrConst;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.